# Calculator freezes after initial inputs

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote this code to calculate something called a B-Factor. Everything works out great initially. You input your pressure and temperature and the B-Factor comes out. But, when I go to enter new values for pressure and temperature - the app seems to freeze.

My code is as follows:

```
import Foundation
class bFactorFormula {
    var NK_VALUES:[Double] = [0.924803575275, -0.492448489428, 0.661883336938, -1.92902649201, -0.0622469309629, 0.349943957581, 0.564857472498, -1.61720005987, -0.481395031883, 0.421150636384, -0.0161962230825, 0.172100994165, 0.00735448924933, 0.0168077305479, -0.00107626664179, -0.0137318088513, 0.000635466899859, 0.00304432279419, -0.0435762336045, -0.0723174889316, 0.0389644315272, -0.021220136391, 0.00408822981509, -0.0000551990017984, -0.0462016716479, -0.00300311716011, 0.0368825891208, -0.0025585684622, 0.00896915264558, -0.0044151337035, 0.00133722924858, 0.000264832491957, 19.6688194015, -20.915560073, 0.0167788306989, 2627.67566274]
    var IK_VALUES:[Double] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 5, 8, 3, 5, 6, 9, 1, 1, 3, 2]
    var JK_VALUES:[Double] = [0.25, 0.875, 0.5, 0.875, 0.375, 0.75, 0.5, 0.75, 2, 1.25, 3.5, 1, 0.5, 3, 0, 2.75, 0.75, 2.5, 4, 6, 6, 3, 3, 6, 16, 11, 15, 12, 12, 7, 4, 16, 0, 1, 2, 3]
    var LK_VALUES:[Double] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    var PK_VALUES:[Double] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 15, 25]
    var BK_VALUES:[Double] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0325, 325, 300, 275]
    var UK_VALUES:[Double] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.16, 1.16, 1.13, 1.25]
    var R_CONST = 8.31451
    var T_C:Double = 126.192
    var P_C:Double = 3.3958
    var MOLECULAR_WEIGHT:Double = 28.01348
    var DENSITY_STP:Double = 1.1851
    var RHO_C:Double = 11.1839

    // DECLARE INPUT VARIABLES
    var n2TemperatureInput:Double
    var n2PressureInput: Double
    var tempK:Double {
        get {
            return n2TemperatureInput + 273.15
        }
    }
    var tempR:Double {
        get {
            return T_C / tempK
        }
    }
    var pTarget:Double {
        get {
            return (n2PressureInput * 1000000) + 101325
        }
    }

    init (setBFactorTemperature:Double, setBFactorPressure:Double) {
        self.n2TemperatureInput = setBFactorTemperature
        self.n2PressureInput = setBFactorPressure
    }

    var rhoCurrent:Double = 0
    var rhoHigh:Double = 0
    var rhoLow:Double = 0
    var diffAggregate:Double = 0
    var diffSegment:Double = 0
    var iFactor:Double = 0
    var bFactor:Double = 0
    //
    // kIndex defined in the while-loop
    // var kIndex:Double = 0
    //
    var pCalc:Double = 0
    var zDiff:Double = 0
    var rhoR:Double = 0

    func retRhoCurrent() -> Double {

        while abs(pTarget - pCalc) > 1 {

            //
            // SET rhoCurrent
            //

            if (pTarget > pCalc) {
                rhoLow = rhoCurrent
                if(rhoCurrent >= rhoHigh) {
                    rhoCurrent += RHO_C
                    rhoHigh = rhoCurrent
                } else {
                    rhoCurrent += ((rhoHigh - rhoCurrent)/2)
                }
            } else {
                rhoHigh = rhoCurrent
                rhoCurrent += ((rhoLow - rhoCurrent)/2)
            }

            //
            // SET rhoR
            //

            rhoR = rhoCurrent / RHO_C

            //
            // SET DIFFERENTIAL
            //
            diffAggregate = 0
            for var kIndex = 0; kIndex < NK_VALUES.count; ++kIndex {
                diffSegment = NK_VALUES[kIndex]
                diffSegment *= pow(rhoR, IK_VALUES[kIndex])
                diffSegment *= pow(tempR, JK_VALUES[kIndex])
                iFactor = 0
                if LK_VALUES[kIndex] > 0 {
                    diffSegment *= exp(-1 * pow(rhoR, LK_VALUES[kIndex]))
                    iFactor = LK_VALUES[kIndex] * pow(rhoR, LK_VALUES[kIndex])
                }
                if PK_VALUES[kIndex] > 0 {
                    diffSegment *= exp(-1 * PK_VALUES[kIndex] * pow(rhoR, 2) - BK_VALUES[kIndex] * pow(tempR - UK_VALUES[kIndex], 2))
                    iFactor = 2 * rhoR * PK_VALUES[kIndex] * (rhoR - 1)
                }
                diffAggregate += (diffSegment * (IK_VALUES[kIndex] - iFactor))
            }

            //
            // SET pCalc
            //
            zDiff = 1 + diffAggregate
            pCalc = zDiff * R_CONST * 1000 * tempK * rhoCurrent
        }
        return rhoCurrent
    }
}
```

I was thinking I may need some kind of a "refresh" command but I'm not sure how to go that route if it is the correct thing to do.

Also - I want to show you guys my ViewController to see how I'm doing this to perform its action.

```
import UIKit

extension Double {
func format(f: String) -> String {
    return NSString(format: "%\(f)f", self) as String
}
}

class NitrogenViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var bFactorPressureInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bFactorTemperatureInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bFactorResults: UILabel!

var calcBFactor = bFactorFormula(setBFactorTemperature: 10, setBFactorPressure: 10)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func bFactorButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    calcBFactor.n2PressureInput = Double((bFactorPressureInput.text as NSString).doubleValue)
    calcBFactor.n2TemperatureInput = Double((bFactorTemperatureInput.text as NSString).doubleValue)
    var rhoCurrentReturned = calcBFactor.retRhoCurrent()
    var bFactorResult = rhoCurrentReturned * (28.01348/1.1851)
    var bFactorResultFormat = "0.2"
    bFactorResults.text = "The B-Factor is \(bFactorResult.format(bFactorResultFormat)) scm/m3"
}
```

I'm thinking its something to do with my view controller code. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it halt (with CPU at 0%) or lock up (with CPU at 100%)?

Comment: You need to add the code that is using this class. This test tuns twice with no problem: `let x = bFactorFormula(setBFactorTemperature:10.0, setBFactorPressure:10.0)`
`let y = x.retRhoCurrent()`
`print(y)`
`print(y)` Outputs: 4.31804172998667
4.31804172998667

Comment: @Aggressor There is no error that pops up, it just ends up in a perpetual load that ends up freezing my simulation to the point that I just need to force quit the simulation.

Comment: @DanLoughney how would I go to check that? As I mentioned in my reply to Aggressor, it doesn't do any crashes...just ends up freezing to the point where I force quit.

Comment: @zaph where would I add this line of code?

Comment: Its stuck in the while loop then :)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the loop and single step watching the values. `NSLog()` the entry values. IOW debug the code.

Comment: Start your app in Xcode. Open the Debug Navigator (Command 6) and click on the CPU history. This will show you whether your CPU is 0% where you are halted or 100% where you are stuck in a tight/infinite loop.

Comment: @DanLoughney you are correct. My CPU does go to 100% when it freezes. That must mean I'm stuck in an infinite loop correct? ahh...time to debug..

Comment: What are your input values for both runs?

Comment: @DanLoughney It can be anything. But for testing purposes I'll do 10 and 10...then for my second one I'll just do like 50 (temp) and 30 (pressure). When doing 10 & 10, the output should be 102. And for 50 and 30 it should be 229.94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are initializing pCalc to 0 when the `bFactorFormula` class is initialized. That's fine. But after the first run pCalc is 10101321.0261427 and when you run the calculation again, you never fall out of your `while` loop.

So you can create a new bFactorForumula object for each run in the IBAction code or you can set pCalc = 0 at the top of `retRhoCurrent`.

Comment: I've tried setting pCalc=0 at the top of retRhoCurrent, but to no avail. Just to clarify, when you say to set pCalc=0 at the top, do you mean the line right before the start of while-loop?

Comment: In addition to setting pCalc=0, I also set zDiff and rhoCurrent to 0 as well. And now it works! Thanks Dan for your help.